# Web server esp8266 arduino

Tags: android, arduino, ip, esp8266

I have been trying to setup a server with esp8266 but results are always negative. I followed all the instruction of this page http://allaboutee.com/2015/01/20/esp8266-android-application-for-arduino-pin-control/ I even made the app. when I run the program it says server ready but acuattly the webpage is not reachable in chrome. I also brought a 3.3v voltage regulator but then also the result is same.

One thing that I did notice was when the regulator is connected, then the esp8266 doesn't respond to AT commands But when I connect it directly to 3.3v on arduino it responds to AT commands and set up a server only when I send commands one by one.

Please please for gods sake, nature sake, humanity sake help, tell me what to do I am crying ...

Comment: Hey anyone there please answer

Comment: Many regulators require a higher input voltage than their output.  The reason AT commands don't work as a batch is that some complete asynchronously.  You might want to consider nodemcu, it's a lot more capable than the standard AT firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try to test the ESP over a serial monitor and check what is going on.

Use this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial ESP(2, 4); // RX, TX
int baud = 9600; 
void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     while (!Serial){}
     ESP.begin(9600);
     while (!ESP){}
     Serial.println("Starting the program!");
}

void loop() {
     if (ESP.available() > 0) {
         Serial.write(ESP.read());
     }

     if (Serial.available() > 0) {
         ESP.write(Serial.read());
     }
}
```

If the Firmware is old, the ESP might reset itself and even freeze pretty often. To check the current firmware version try AT+GMR.

After successfully configuring the ESP as softAP & webserver try to connect to the AP and type it's IP address (AT+CIFSR) into the web browser.
If you get a request to the serial port starting with +IPD you've managed to send a HTTP request to the ESP.